# How to use ORDER BY to place last the row when a column IS NOT empty string?

Tags: mysql

I want to place last if a column (lets say 'answer') is not empty string.

My base query:

```
SELECT messages.id
     , users.username
     , messages.answer 
  FROM MESSAGES 
  JOIN users 
    ON messages.user_id = users.id 
 ORDER 
    BY ?
";
```

How to use ORDER BY to place NON EMPTY users.answer to the bottom?

(It is like a ticket system so answered tickets should be last)

Comment: What is "EMPTY"? Zero-length string? NULL? A string of spaces only?

Comment: do you want to sort answer in desc or asc order?

Comment: I used navicat and i set default to "Empty string" I assuem it is this: "" or '' so "Zero-Lenght string"

Comment: @aatwork I think it's not really matter, i just want them to be last when it is empty string. I probably will use another oder by next to it by a date column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT messages.id, users.username, messages.answer FROM MESSAGES INNER JOIN users ON messages.user_id = users.id ORDER BY answer desc;
```

If you just want empty or null values to be at bottom, use "desc" as above. It should do the job.

Comment: It works but not with desc but asc. I thought it is way harder to do lol thanks.

Comment: Cool. Yeah. If you want empty or null values at bottom, use desc. If you want non-empty values at bottom use asc.